# MonoMac reverting application icon change

Tags: macos, mono, icons, monomac

I'm converting a small c# application from windows to osx using MonoDevelop and MonoMac.
I've changed the icon of the app using the Info.plist located inside the app contents directory by adding the CFBundleIconFile and the name of my icon, residing in the Resources directory.
So far everything is fine, finder acknowledges the icon and it is correct in the "Get info"-page.
However, when I start the app the correct icon starts bouncing, but a second later it changes into the MonoMac monkey(?) icon.
Is there some way for me to keep my icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Windows Forms or GTK, it's likely because you have a Win32 icon set in your project's options, which either will pick up and use.

Either that, or you're setting MyForm.Icon to something explicit in the code.

If you're not using Windows Forms or GTK, then there's not much that would cause that, as I don't believe there's an easy way for MonoMac apps to do this.

Comment: I'm using windows forms.
But removing the win32 icon (which I had set), cleaning and rebuilding the app didn't solve the problem.
Can I force the icon from the code?

Comment: I believe if you do as I mention above, such as MyForm.Icon = new Icon("MyIconFile.ico"); (or better, from a resource stream), then that should do it..

Comment: I'm already doing that (since that's how we've set the icon on windows). Tried removing that and it made the mono monkey pixelated.

Comment: @Birken: Hm, it seems to work for me.  Here's a sample project that sets the icon: http://db.tt/xIIG6NMj

Comment: Thanks, it seems I had to read it from a stream to get it to work.